# Rails each loop insert tag every 6 items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have X number of image objects that I need to loop through in a view and want to create a new div every 6 objects or so (for a gallery).

I have looked at cycle but it seems to change every other record. Does anyone know of a way to insert code into a view every 6 times?

I could probably do it with nested loops but I am kinda stumped on this one.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable#each_slice` in conjunction with `#each` to avoid inline calculations.  `each_slice` breaks the array into chunks of n, in this case 6.

```
<% @images.each_slice(6) do |slice| -%>
  <div class="gallery">
    <% slice.each do |image| -%>
      <%= image_tag(image.url, :alt => image.alt) %>
    <% end -%>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: That seems like a more conventional way to do it.. I'll give a a try.

Comment: Thanks Thorn, I prefer this method to keep my views clean. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this works great. A lot more sexy than keeping a counter.

Comment: How would you handle this when using an interator that doesn't support this thing like @documents.each_hit_with_result in Solr?

Comment: I haven't used Solr before, but I see that method returns an enumerable if no block is given (typical Ruby behavior). In that case, you should be able to just chain on top of it: `@documents.each_hit_with_result.each_slice(6) do |slice|`. Source: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/lib/sunspot/search/hit_enumerable.rb#L49

Comment: It works perfectly. But do you have any idea if we can find the index as well, I mean method each_slice with index as array ?

Comment: I got my answer myself. In fact, I found we can use each_slice_with index as well.

Comment: Whooa, this is so comfortable

Answer (score 14):

This is a Ruby question. You can meld this into whatever your view is trying to do.

```
@list.each_with_index do |item, idx|
  if((idx + 1) % 6 == 0)
    # Poop out the div
  end
  # Do whatever needs to be done on each iteration here.
end
```

Comment: Great solution @jdl, this works perfect for injecting an ad partial into a looped list (which I had trouble figuring out in the past).