# Manually output HAML start and end tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have some code:

```
- count = 0
- @clients.each do |client|
  %div{:class => "grid_2#{(" alpha" if (count % 3) == 0) || (" omega push_2" if (count % 3) == 2) || " push_1"}"}= link_to h(client.name), client    
  - count += 1
```

I want to output an opening `div` tag right after the `each` statement if the `(count % 3) == 0` and out put the end tag at the end of the block if the `(count % 3) == 2` but I can't figure out how to get HAML to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice solution that was posted here a few weeks ago. It's not in Haml, but the idea is the same.

[Rails each loop insert tag every 6 items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851915/rails-each-loop-insert-tag-every-6-items)