# Render n objects at a time, inserting code then repeating for the next n objects - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, loops, render

Newbie and would really appreciate some help rendering objects in sets of 3's.

I currently display a list of objects with render:

```
<%= render @gifts %>
```

Each object has some characteristics that render from the partial _gift.html.erb

This all works fine. However, how do I loop through all the @gifts objects wrapping every 3 objects with a div? Desired result is something like:

```
<div class="row-fluid>
# The first 3 objects from @gifts
</div>

<div class="row-fluid>
# The next 3 objects from @gifts
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @gifts.each_slice(3) do |slice| %>
  <div class="row-fluid>
    # slice now is a 3 element array, iterate over it and render as you see fit
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm more of a HAML guy, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

`each_slice` is what you're looking for. It's covered in better detail here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2852103/9465

Answer (score 0):

Also consider in_groups_of (a Rails monkey-patch to Array):

http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of