# Why many people use "-%>" instead of "%>" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style, convention

Sorry for this question, i think its more offtopic, but i couldn't find anything on google!

I saw now multiple times that a lot of people use `-%>` instead of just `%>`. Whats the sense?

Example:

```
<% @images.each_slice(6) do |slice| -%>
  <div class="gallery">
    <% slice.each do |image| -%>
      <%= image_tag(image.url, :alt => image.alt) %>
    <% end -%>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```

Source: [Rails each loop insert tag every 6 items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851915/rails-each-loop-insert-tag-every-6-items)

Here he has also used `-%>` for all  blocks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would like to add some resources that I know about ERB :

- Rails extends *`ERB`*, so that you can suppress the *newline* simply by adding a trailing hyphen to tags in Rails templates:

  ```
  <ul>
    <% for @item in @items -%>
      <li><%= @item %></li>
    <% end -%>
  </ul>
  ```
- Comment markers use a *`hash`* sign:

  ```
   <%# This is just a comment %>
  ```
- A tag with an *`equals sign`* indicates that enclosed code is an expression, and that the renderer should substitute the code element with the result of the code (as a string) when it renders the template. Use an expression to embed a line of code into the template, or to display the contents of a variable:

  ```
   Hello, <%= @name %>.
   Today is <%= Time.now.strftime('%A') %>.
  ```
- With one *`equal sign`* the string will be encoded. To avoid encoding, you can use two *`equals signs`* (or [raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw)):

  ```
      Hello, <%== @unencodedOutput %>
  ```
- Tags without the *`equals`* sign denote that the enclosed code is a *scriptlet*. Each scriptlet is caught and executed, and the final result of the code is then injected in to the output at the point of the *scriptlet*.

  ```
  <ul>
    <% for @item in @shopping_list %>
      <li><%= @item %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  ```

  Scriptlets are most commonly used for embedding loops or conditional logic into templates:

Read [*An Introduction to ERB Templating*](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/) to know more.