# how to use link tag in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to use link tag in ruby on rails?

```
<%  link_to "Stephen Weber", "home.html" %>
```

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 2):

You have missed `=`, its should be `<%=`

```
<%=  link_to "Stephen Weber", "home.html" %>
```

Comment: i didn't get the proper output.its say No route matches "/home.html" with {:method=>:get} what can i do?please help me.thank u for advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of view renderer engine you are using, if you are using Haml-rails then syntax is slightly different, remember that Haml views are indentation based just like python :

```
= link_to "Stephen Weber", "Home.html", {class: 'any_class_name', id: 'try_to_use_unique', style: 'margin:'''}
```

If you are using erb, then syntax is:

```
 <%= link_to "Stephen Weber", "Home.html", {class: 'any_class_name', id: 'try_to_use_unique', style: 'margin:'''} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `=` in

```
<% link_to "Stephen Weber", "home.html" %>
```

It should be

```
<%= link_to "Stephen Weber", "home.html" %>
```

For more details on Rails ERB format, go to [Why many people use "-%>" instead of "%>" in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789543/why-many-people-use-instead-of-in-rails/19789630#19789630)