# What is the exactly purpose of the "-" character within tags in ERB templates?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, embedded-ruby

I have been overwriting some Rails generator templates and noticed that there is another type of tag used to put Ruby code there:

```
<%- code here -%>
<%- code here %>
<% code here -%>
```

I checked the Rails documentation and there says:

> To suppress leading and trailing whitespaces, you can use <%- -%> interchangeably with <% and %>.

But, i didn't understand exactly how to add "-" to the right, left or both sides of tags makes the whitespaces are removed.

My code works well, so I just want to clear up this specific doubt. Thanks!

Comment: What is not covered be the other answer: `-%>` was used to avoid line breaks after the ERB expression. But since version Rails 3.2 Erubis is used template engine and Erubis suppresses line breaks automatically. Therefore `-%>` is kind of obsolete in Rails code nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% %>
```

Executes the ruby code within the brackets.

```
<%= %>
```

Prints something into erb file.

```
<% -%>
```

Avoids line break after expression.

```
<%# %>
```

Comments out code within brackets; not sent to client (as opposed to HTML comments).

```
<%- and -%> suppress leading and trailing whitespace
```

visit http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html for more information

[Why many people use "-%>" instead of "%>" in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789543/why-many-people-use-instead-of-in-rails/19789630#19789630) question has answers in details

Comment: Appears to have been drawn from this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/rails-erb-syntax/7996827#7996827 See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing