# What is the difference between these two symbols in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= -%>
<%= %>
```

I am confused about this. Anyone can tell me details? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= %>` prints something into `ERB` template

`<%= -%>` prints something into `ERB` template and avoids line break after expression.

Take a look here for details [Why many people use "-%>" instead of "%>" in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789543/why-many-people-use-instead-of-in-rails/19789630#19789630)

Comment: Thank you but I tried to iterate an array in both ways they generate the same html source code.