# Ruhoh - Insert Tag every x items

Tags: ruby, mustache, ruhoh

I'm new to Ruby and Ruhoh and have I am trying to do something like "[Rails each loop insert tag every 6 items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851915/rails-each-loop-insert-tag-every-6-items)" but I am using Ruhoh.

Basically, I have a list of posts and every 3 posts I want to create a new row div.

I have looked through all the Ruhoh documentation and there doesn't appear to be an easy way to do this. I think I need to create a plugin in Ruhoh for a collection, but having no experience in ruby I don't really understand what I am doing. Any help or guidance in the right direction would be great,

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly new to ruby myself, however I think this solution meets your needs!

Create a new file in the `plugin` directory called `pages_collection_view_addons.rb` (if it doesn't already exist).

Add this to that file:

```
module PagesCollectionViewAddons
  def chunks(n = 3)
    # Get all the pages
    pages = all
    chunks = []

    # Split the 'pages' array into chunks of size n
    pages.each_slice(n) { |slice|
        chunks.push({pieces: slice})
    }
    chunks
  end
end

# Inform Ruhoh of this new addon
Ruhoh::Resources::Pages::CollectionView.send(:include, PagesCollectionViewAddons)
```

In your template add something such as:

```
{{# posts.chunks}}
  <div class="row">
       {{# pieces }}
          <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
       {{/ pieces }} 
  </div>
{{/ posts.chunks }}
```

This will iterate over each of the chunks where each chunk looks like:

`{pieces: [post1, post2, post3]}`

Hope this helps.