# rails 3.2 / activerecord - how to display 30 values from AR in a table with 3 columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose the query `customer_list = Customers.where ("state = ?", 'CA').order('first_name ASC')` returns 30 customers, and the field .first_name has their first name.

I want to display their names in an html table with 3 more or less equal columns, eg, I want to fill the table as I go, wrapping to a new row each 3rd value.

```
Aaron    Amy    Andy
Arny     Beth   Bill
Bob      Carl   Charlie
etc etc
```

What is the 'ruby way' to flow the records into such a table's cells?

I could use .find_in_batches to grab 3 at a time, then iterate through the three for each column, but I suspect that's not the elegant ruby way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The each_slice helper method accepts a number n and then breaks the array into chunks of n, in this case 3.

```
<% @customer_list.each_slice(3) do |slice| -%>
 <tr>
  <% slice.each do |customer| -%>
    <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
  <% end -%>
 <tr>
<% end -%>
```

See the [documentations](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851915/rails-each-loop-insert-tag-every-6-items).

Comment: This is VASTLY superior to using find_in_batches() because find_in_batches does NOT respect the order() whereas each_slice() does respect the order().

Answer (score -1):

You could always do a simple:

```
<tr>
<%
i=1
customer_list.each do |customer|
if(i%3==0) then 
i=1%>
</tr><tr>
<%
end
%>
<td><%=customer.first_name%></td>
<%
i+=1
end
%>
</tr>
```

I'm not sure if there's a "Ruby way of doing it", though I'm by no means an expert.