# col-sm-2 in loop under row

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my loop I am running in a rails helper method.

```
part_child_option.each do |o|

  html += "<div class='col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper'>"
  html += "<label class = 'p_name' for='#{attr_name}'>"

    html += image_tag o.photo(:small), class: "tick_option_img",
      html += "</label>"
      html += "</div>"
    end
    html.html_safe
end
```

I have a problem now. class `col-sm-2` is there, so It is under  a class `row` in my view. The row is outside of my helper and hence I am not able to loop it.

The pointed solution doesn't have such scenario

Now I want my `row` class to close once the `col-sm-2` is done with six times. And then I want to start the class `row` again and everything same as above in my class row.

I hope the question is clear now.

How can this be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails each loop insert tag every 6 items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851915/rails-each-loop-insert-tag-every-6-items)

Comment: not able to integrate in my helper. My row is in my view

Answer (score 2):

you are asking same question that already asked. please have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851915/rails-each-loop-insert-tag-every-6-items)

user `each_slice` to make chunks of 6 of your array then iterate each loop.

e.g

```
array.each_slice(6) do |chunk|
  chunk.each do |o|
   end 
end
```

in your case

```
rows = ""
part_child_option.each_slice(6) do | six_o |
  row = "<div class='row'>"
  six_o.each do | o |
     row += "your logic"
  end 
  row  += "</div>"
  rows += row
end
```

Comment: how can I integrate It in my above helper,

Comment: I updated my answer according to your problem. now it can help you I suppose.

Comment: I tried almost similar answer, It didnt work. See my row is in my view. I have `col-sm-2` which I am looping 6 times, the seventh time It comes I want to go to next line.


In the above code It seems you are looping the whole row

Comment: The optimal solution that is possible is create rows in helper  and feed in html view. remove row div from view and place this method there

Comment: yes, I am trying that only..

I created another helper, names tic_tac, copied everything from previous method and added row there and removed row from view.

But getting wrong number of arguments error

http://pastebin.com/Bb5XiLy7

Here's the helper, can you see anything missing?

Comment: sorry brother this site is blocked in our country you can past code in comment.

Comment: u missed a inner loop which will actually create 6 col-sm-2. I updated it a little [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/asadalibhatti/wayw1yL6/1/)

Comment: Damn, yes. I was actually using thay but outside of my row and hence each row was getting one image.

Thanks Asad.