# undefined id error when trying to loop helper after 6 items or classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Got this in my view

```
 <% elsif ["radio", "checkbox"].include?(part_child.display_type) %>  
   <%=   tick_tag_slice  part_child%>
 <% end %>
```

calling `tic_tag_slice` from the helper.

below is my helper of the same

```
  def tick_tag_slice(part_child)
render_type = part_child.display_type == "radio" ? "radio_button_tag" : "check_box_tag"
html = ""
part_child_option = parts_position(part_child.options)

part_child_option.  each_slice(6) do |o|
  html += "<div class = 'row'>"
  html += "<div class='col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper'>"
  html += "<label class = 'p_name' for='#{attr_name}'>"
    "data-part-type" =>"#{part_child.display_type}",
    html += image_tag o.photo(:small), class: "tick_option_img",
        "data-option-name" => o.name
      html += "</label>"
      html += "</div>"
      html += "</div>"

  end
    html.html_safe
end
```

Here I am trying to run each loop after every `col-sm-2`, I am getting thi s error when I am trying to run the app.

> undefined method `id' for Array:0x007f0e282d61c0>

The error line it shows in the view where there's nothing as `id`.

Tried to get t[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851915/rails-each-loop-insert-tag-every-6-items) but couldn't get it working

Please help me figutr this out.

Comment: Can you show us your array contents?

Comment: hang about.. what's `part_child_option`, is that meant to be `part_child.option`?

Comment: No, that is all right, nothing wrong there, missed a section of code while putting the question

Comment: Ok that's clearer. Thanks

Comment: @ccai didn't get you. 
I believe you are asking me the content of class. It's images

Answer (score 0):

`Array#each_slice` returns an array of results, so your `o` variable yielded to the block needs to be `each`ed over again to give your six entries.

From the docs on [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html):

```
(1..10).each_slice(3) { |a| p a }
# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```

I don't see `id` referenced in the code above but there may be some method relying on `o` being a single object there.

Comment: It's `o.photo(:small)` - `o` is an array here, not an object.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `each_slice` returns the enumerable split into enumerables of that size, so inside that loop you would then need to `#each` the `o` variable to get your actual object with the `photo` method.

Comment: If id is not referenced how come I am getting that error.

Comment: Got it. I was missing a loop to generate 6 `col-sm-2`

No idea about that ID refrencing though. 

Thanks peter